# Django: Override Debug=True from manage.py runserver command

Tags: django

Is there an easy way to tell Django's `runserver` to override a single variable in the `settings.py` file?

I would love to be able to call:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 Debug=False
```

Any thoughts?

Motive:  have a particular site where there are hundreds of database queries to show or save a particular page, I'd like to be able to turn off debug quickly without having to edit my settings file (which has the possibility of being forgotten).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you have two options

The simplest is probably a custom settings override, something like:

```
# no_debug_settings.py

# pull in the normal settings
from settings import *

# no debug for us
DEBUG = False
```

Now, when you want to start without debugging, you'd run:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=no_debug_settings 0.0.0.0:8000
```

As an alternative, you could just customise your `manage.py` file. That imports settings, and passes it to the `execute_manager`. If you added some code between the import and the call, you could have it check for extra arguments and alter the settings as needed. It's a bit more fiddly and prone to break / be forgotten, so I'd suggest the override settings wrapper is probably your best way to go.

Comment: the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env var can be used to direct an environment at a particular settings file.

Answer (score 16):

I edited my `settings.py` file with a conditional block, like this:

```
import os  # If needed.

if os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG'):
    print("Debug is enabled.")
    DEBUG = True
    # When not specified, ALLOW_HOSTS defaults to:
    # ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']
else:
    DEBUG = False
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

Then, run your server by passing the environmental variable `DJANGO_DEBUG=1`. You can name the variable anything you want so long as you are consistent:

```
DJANGO_DEBUG=1 python -Wall manage.py runserver
```

Omit that environmental variable when calling `manage.py` to disable debug (because setting it to any value, including `0` will still make it true to the Python code.)

**Update:** A commenter stated that the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` directive is ignored when `DEBUG` is `True`. This is only true in older versions of Django. The current behavior is to honor `ALLOWED_HOSTS` or default to localhost addresses if it isn't specified when `DEBUG` is enabled. My answer is updated to reflect this as a minor correction.

This is sourced from the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts):

> When DEBUG is True and ALLOWED_HOSTS is empty, the host is 
>   validated against ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']

Additionally, it states that the behavior your comment on is now outdated in a few major version lines:

> In older versions, ALLOWED_HOSTS wasn’t checked if DEBUG=True. 
>   This was also changed in Django 1.10.3, 1.9.11, and 1.8.16 to prevent a 
>   DNS rebinding attack.

Comment: `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is ignored when `DEBUG` is on. If you only want to give access from localhost, the easiest way to control that is to set which interface it binds to with the `runserver` command line.

Comment: Only in *older* versions of Django. Please see my updated answer.